# Sendto() socket method sends junk on short strings

Tags: c++, sockets

I have server and client to send/receive a string through windows sockets.

Client code (sender):

```
string c = "Haha";

sprintf(temp.Buffer, c.c_str());
temp.len = c.size();
int sent = 0;
if ((sent = sendto(s, temp.Buffer, temp.len + 1, 0, (SOCKADDR*)&sa_in, sizeof(sa_in))) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    cout << "Send request method failed\n";
}
```

Server code (receiver):

```
if (!(outfds = select (1 , &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL))) {//timed out
    cout << "timed out";
}
if (outfds == 1)
{
    fromlen = sizeof sa_in;
    received = recvfrom(s, buf, 2048, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&sa_in, &fromlen);
}
```

In the server, I've noticed if the string I send from the client is smaller than a number of bytes (like 0-8~) the 'buf' variable contains garbage at the end of it. For example, I'll send the string "ahah" and the server will receive a string similar to "ahah0`". If I send "Hello World", it receives it correctly. The char buffers in the client and server are both of size 2048.

A solution I found to this was to add +1 to the length in the sendto() method. I don't want this to bite me in the a** later if I send something bigger than the maximum allowed size.

Does anyone know where this is coming from and do you have a better solution?

Edit: The number of bytes sent and received is always the same.

Thanks

Comment: `sprintf(temp.Buffer, c.c_str());`?  What does that do?  Are you sure you didn't mean `strcpy()`?

Comment: `+1` will also send the `'\0` termination of the C string. Did you initiate your `buf` in the receiver with zero values? And `sprintf(temp.Buffer,c.c_str())` provides a potential format string attack, use `strncpy` or `sprintf(temp.Buffer,"%s",c.c_str())` instead.

Comment: I tried with strcpy, still got the same error. I did not initiate buf with zero values, but how would that make any difference for longer strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not transmitting the trailing `'\0'` char. Does your protocol specify a nul-terminated string?  If so, change your client thus:

```
sendto( ..., temp.len+1, ...);
```

If your protocol specifies that you do not send the nul termination, then modify your server thus:

```
fromlen = sizeof sa_in;
received = recvfrom(s, buf, 2048, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&sa_in, &fromlen);
if(received >= 0)
    buf[received] = 0;
```

If your protocol does not specify, then *stop coding now* and finish writing your protocol spec.